ICS file ignores VALARM when Attendee is specified
I have a ICS file that I'm emailing myself.  When I open the ICS file it is added to macos/ios Calendar App with the reminder specified in VALARM.  However if I include ATTENDEE and email it to myself, I don't need to open the ICS file, instead the Calendar app automatically sees it and asks me to accept/decline the event.  However, Accepting it will make the default reminder occur 30 minutes before the event.  It ignores what I have specified in VALARM.
I want to be able to specify the default reminders when I specify the attendee.  here is an example of my ICS file which specifies a reminder 60 minutes before the event which gets ignored.
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//zoom.us//iCalendar Event//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:123456789
ORGANIZER;CN=Cool Events:mailto:organizeremail@gmail.com
ATTENDEE:mailto:emailofattendee@gmail.com
DTSTAMP:20241114T160000
DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20241120T160000
DTEND;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20241120T180000
SUMMARY:Wonderful Summary
LOCATION:1234 A street
DESCRIPTION:Wonderful Description
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT60M
REPEAT:2
DURATION:PT45M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR


This question does not seem to be a programming question? Asking because Stack Overflow is for programming questions only.
